# Using a Annotation with same name as imported Class in Maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, annotations, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have to use @ApiResponse by importing io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.ApiResponse but then, I have a class which also has to be used named as ApiResponse and i cannot change this class name. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: If you cannot change the name of either type, then for one or both types use their fully qualified names instead of importing them.